# Show full ArrayList in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show the whole array separated with a comma in the HTML body. So far, the whole ArrayList is the result of the multiplication of specific values, so if the value is 2, then ArrayList will be (2,4,6,8,10).

I have created the multiplication function using js and in console, I can see the ArrayList. But whenever I am trying to show this list in HTML using innerHTML, I only can see 10 (for multiplication of 2), but can not visualize the whole list.

```js
function showData() {
  var theSelect = demoForm.part;
  var secondP = document.getElementById('secondP');

  var num = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value
  console.log("this is" + num)

  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    result = i * num;
    console.log("List is" + result);
  }
  secondP.innerHTML = ('Its Standerd Pack is: ' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value + " we have to choose" + result);
}
```

```html
<p id="secondP"></p>
```

Current output is:

```
Its Standard Pack is: 2 we have to choose 10
```

Expected output:*

```
Its Standard Pack is: 2 we have to choose 2,4,8,10
```

Any suggestion on how to do that. Thank you very much

Comment: `resullt` isn't an array, it's just a single number.

Comment: You're missing `}` at the end of the function, and you never call the function.

Comment: FYI, you can just use `theSelect.value`.

Comment: You should set `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: "I can see the ArrayList" - JavaScript does not have an `ArrayList` type - only `Array`, (and unlike arrays in most languages, JavaScript's `Array` type is dynamically sized, fwiw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `result` an array and push onto it, not reassign it.

```js
function showData() {
  var secondP = document.getElementById('secondP');

  var num = 2
  console.log("this is" + num)
  let result = [];
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    result.push(i * num);
  }
  secondP.innerHTML = ('Its Standerd Pack is: ' + num + " we have to choose " + result.join(", "));
}

showData();
```

```html
<p id="secondP"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I got it wrong but if you were having trouble to show the items in an array separated by a comma (or anything else),
the simplest solution I have is arr.join(", ")

or a neat code

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, `a`, `b`, `c`];

function showFullArrayList(arr) {
  console.log(arr.join(`, `));
}

showFullArrayList(arr);
```